# Change constructor properties in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, constructor, properties

I have one question about react constructor, because I used angular and accustomed to to way binding behavior. And I don't know how change properties from constructor. And explain me how I can't do that and explain me how I can achieve my goal.

```
class example extends React.Component {
 constructor(){
   super();
   this.changeExample = this.changeExample.bind(this)
   this.valueExample = 'Hello Example'
 }
 changeExample() {
   this.valueExample = 'Hello StackOverFlow'
 }
 render()
 return(
   <button onClick="{this.chnageExample}"></button>
   <div className="example">{this.valueExample}</div>
 )

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you should use valueExample in state. In contructor, you set initial state for component

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = { valueExample: "" }
}

changeExample(){
   this.setState({ valueExample: "Hello ..." })
}
```

When you click button then component will re-render, and valueExample will update in view.

In react, components (view) only update (re-render) when state or props of component changed. 
You can read in doc of reactjs 
https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html
https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: Yes I know it, but I would like validate form and I would like live validate pattern, and if I use this.state and one input is correct all form going to correct

Comment: Why is one input correct then all form correct? When input change, you update value of input in state. If you need validate then you need check all values of each input in state. You can use componentWillUpdate(nextState, nextProps)

Answer (score 0):

He have right.First must use this.state, because we must  set initial state, and then with this.setState get new value ( no meter pros or state of witch we wish)